# Apache Cordova: running cordova run browser without launching browser app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have Apache Cordova app on my dedicated server. Access it via console. But when I run 
    'cordova run browser'
I get error

Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
CTRL + C to shut down
Error executing "google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova http://localhost:8000/index.html": [21075:21075:0423/054416:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)] Gtk: cannot open display:

And thus I cannot start test server with my app. How I can avoid automatic browser start?
Thanx

Comment: Try serving the content instead. [Cordova server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-server). It might have some plugin limitations.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's been a while but what I did to avoid opening browser was editing the file under './platforms/browser/cordova/run' and changing the line:

```
return cordovaServe.launchBrowser({target: args.target, url: projectUrl});
```

to:

```
return cordovaServe;
```

Comment: A side note, commenting out the line also works for some reason.

Comment: That line of code is now in `./platforms/browser/cordova/lib/run`.

Comment: And the content is now `return server.launchBrowser({ 'target': args.target, 'url': projectUrl });` (line 60). Changing it to `return server;` works for me.

Comment: Where is it now (cordova -v 10.0.0)?